# Laravel homestead.yaml not showing

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to install homestead. But when I come tot the point that I've to fill in: "bash init.sh" the Homestead.yaml won't show up?

I'm using osx.

What am I doing wrong?

Thankss

Comment: Do you verify correct directory? On Windows `homestead.yaml` does NOT appear in same directory but in `.homested` directory in user profile directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd ~
cd .homestead
nano Homestead.yaml
```